# How to get byteArray of file when uploading in Flex 2

Tags: apache-flex

```
     There is a WSDL which have one method which take byteArray & fileName(which i want to write) as a parameter to write a file in local system, the following is the code...

public void writeLocation(byte[] byteToWrite, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    StringBuffer fileLocation = new StringBuffer("D:\\Products\\Device");
    fileLocation.append("\\"+fileName);
    File file = new File(fileLocation.toString());
    BufferedOutputStream bufferWriter = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    try 
    {
        bufferWriter.write(byteToWrite);
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error file Writing....");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try 
        {
            bufferWriter.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

now i am using the flex 2 & to do following :

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:WebService id = "byteCheckUpload" wsdl="http://localhost:8080/XFireTest/xfire/EmployeeService?wsdl" showBusyCursor="true">
        <mx:operation name="writeLocation" fault="writeLocationFH(event)" result="writeLocationRH()"/>
    <mx:WebService/>
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;

        private var refUploadFile : FileReference;

        public function uploadFile() : void
        {
            refUploadFile = new  FileReference(); 
            refUploadFile.browse(); 
            refUploadFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,onFileSelect); 
            refUploadFile.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onFileComplete);  
        }

        public function onFileSelect(event : Event) : void
        {
            refUploadFile.load();
        }

        public function onFileComplete(event : Event) : void
        {
            refUploadFile = event.currentTarget as FileReference; 
            var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
            refUploadFile.data.readBytes(data,0,refUploadFile.data.length); 

            byteCheckUpload.writeLocation(data, refUploadFile.name) 
        }

        public function writeLocationFH(event : FaultEvent) : void
        {
            Alert.show(event.fault.faultString);    
        }

        public function writeLocationRH() : void
        {
            Alert.show("Please check the Location .... !!!");
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Button x="308" y="156" label="Click button to Upload a file" click="uploadFile();"/>
```

but the flex 2 showing the error when i searched i found out in flex 2 there is no "data" property. so i am unable to create the selected object into byteArray.. Can any one help me how i do that.. & don't want to use HTTPService (POST method)..

Please Help.. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

That feature is not available in FP 9. You need to [target your application for flash player 10](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Targeting+Flash+Player+10).

This was intended for Flex 3 however, so it may or may not work for older versions of the framework. Either way, the issue is that you are using a feature not available in the version you're using.